# Concrete Matlab class with abstract property member class, is this possible?

Tags: matlab

New to Matlab but forced to use it for a new work project... I'm coming from a C++ background, but maybe I should not try to emulate coding paradigms from C++ with Matlab. I'm trying to figure out how to have a abstract class property that gets initialized when the constructor is called with a concrete member. For instance:

```
%AbstractClass.m
classdef (Abstract) AbstractClass < handle
end
```

```
%ConcreteClass.m
classdef ConcreteClass < AbstractClass
end
```

```
%myclass.m
classdef myclass < handle
    properties
        % X {AbstractClass}  % would like to have this be like C++ nullptr 
        %X {AbstractClass} % can't initialize...
        %X % Works, but not safe 
        X {mustBeA(X, 'AbstractClass')} % Suggested, error below    
    end

    methods
        % constructor 
        function obj = myclass( concreteInstanceOfAbstractClass )
            obj.X = concreteInstanceOfAbstractClass 
        end
    end
end
```

But when I try to run this

```
Y = ConcreteClass()
mustBeA(AbstractClass, Y) % no error, fine 
mustBeA(ConcreteClass, Y) % no error, fine 
A = myclass(Y)            % throws error below
```

I get the following error

```
>> A = myclass(Y)
Error using implicit default value of property 'X' of class 'myclass'. Value must be one of the following types: 'AbstractClass'.
```

Is there a way to initialize the class in the constructor using the concrete instance of Abstract class? I have done some searching, but I'm new enough to Matlab that I'm probably not looking in the right places. This would be a very common thing to do in C++.

Comment: Don’t initialize `X` in the properties, just do `properties, X, end`. The constructor can then assign anything to it.

Comment: Thanks Cris, Indeed that might be the only option. It doesn't feel very safe, but I can check in the constructor that the right class type is passed in.

Comment: "doesn't feel very safe" How would it not be safe? If someone assigns something different to `X` then stuff will stop working. They'll learn not to do that. If you need to, make `X` a private property, or add a [setter method](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/property-set-methods.html) that checks the type before assigning it.

Comment: One more comment about this. Type safety is a thing in C++, but not in many other languages. Python and MATLAB have always used “duck typing”, both are attempting to add type safety, but it’s never going to be like C++. And I think you just need to roll with duck typing in these languages.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
properties
    X {mustBeA(X, 'AbstractClass')}
end
```

which is a [property validator](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/validate-property-values.html#bvjrgth) rather than a class constraint.

Further to comments below, I realise the problem is that MATLAB insists on having a default value in the `classdef`. Unfortunately, this makes things difficult. One approach is to supply a valid concrete class as the default value. This works:

```
properties
    X AbstractClass = ConcreteClass
end
```

but requires that the using class knows the name of `ConcreteClass`. Another approach (especially if the property needs to be set only at construction time) is this:

```
classdef Uses
    properties (SetAccess = immutable)
        % No constraints here
        Property
    end
    
    methods
        function obj = Uses(val)
            arguments
                % Enforce constraints here - scalar instance
                % of something inheriting from AbstractClass
                val (1,1) AbstractClass
            end
            obj.Property = val;
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried this, and it makes sense that it should work, but am still getting an error. I amended the original question to reflect this approach.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should really have tried my suggestion before posting. Hm, I think this is annoyingly hard to achieve in a satisfactory way. One unsatisfactory way is to use a concrete instance as the default value.

Comment: That actually doesn't work either X {mustBeA(X,'ConcreteClass')} under properties! I think this design is just not a good fit for Matlab. I can do a sanity check within the constructor to make it safer, but you can't specify the type in the prototype as far as I can tell. A million thanks for your suggestion though, I learned something! I didn't downvote you?

Comment: I think really the problem is that MATLAB class properties _must_ have a valid default value. (If you don't specify one, the default default is `[]` - i.e. empty `double`). Unfortunately, this makes it difficult to specify an abstract class as a constraint for a class property, since that makes it hard to provide a valid default value.